# Como organizar meus modelos em um projeto Angular Cli?

Tags: javascript, front-end, angular

Gostaria de saber se é possível e também se é uma boa prática organizar meus modelos fora de um diretório de um componente. Por exemplo:

Gostaria de manter meus modelos dentro de um diretório chamado "models" no mesmo nível do diretório "app", dentro de "src".

Answer (score 1):

Todo o código da sua aplicação deve ficar dentro da pasta **src** e os respectivos ao seu projeto em **app**.

O que eu faço nos meus projetos normalmente é criar dentro de **src** a seguinte estrutura:

```
src
    /app
        /shared/models
```

E nessa pasta **model** eu coloco todos os arquivos dos models que são compartilhados por toda a aplicação.
O que você sugeriu não está totalmente errado, mas deve ficar dentro de **app**.